# How to get Java Version from batch script?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to get '6' out of the java version output given below

```
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode, sharing)
```

For the same I wrote this batch script

```
set VERSION6="1.6.0_21"
java -version 2>&1 | findstr "version" >ab.txt
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in (ab.txt) do (
  if not %%g == %VERSION6% echo %%g
  echo %%g
)
```

`%%g` displays "1.6.0_21"

May someone guide me to correct direction? I am not much familiar with `for /f`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set VERSION6="1.6.0_21"
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
    @echo Output: %%g
    set JAVAVER=%%g
)
set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:"=%
@echo Output: %JAVAVER%

for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%v in ("%JAVAVER%") do (
    @echo Major: %%v
    @echo Minor: %%w
    @echo Build: %%x
)

endlocal
```

In the first `for` loop, `"tokens=3"` says that we're going to just use the third token from the command output. Rather than redirect the output of the `java -version` command to a file, we can run this command within the `for` loop itself. The carets (`^`) are escape characters, and are needed so we can embed the `>`, `&` and `|` symbols in the command string.

Within the body of the `for` loop, we set a new var, `JAVAVER`, so that we can do some manipulation of the version string later.

The `set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:"=%` command removes the double quotes from around the version string.

The last `for` loop parses the java version string. `delims=.` says we're going to delimit tokens using periods. `tokens=1-3` says we're going to pass the first three tokens from the string to the body of the loop. We can now get the components of the java version string using the explicit variable, `%%v` and the implied variables (next letters in the alphabet) `%%w` and `%%x`.

When I run this on my system I get:

```
Output: "1.6.0_24" 
Output: 1.6.0_24
Major: 1 
Minor: 6 
Build: 0_24
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, that was really cool stuff. Wish i'll write my own someday, but this for /f is pretty confusing for me :(

Comment: There is one more thing I needed to ask related to the above question. If my JAVA_HOME path is set to "c:\Program Files\...." and when I run the script it gets a space and says "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: @Abhishek, try putting double quotes around `%JAVA_HOME%`, like this: `"%JAVA_HOME%"`.

Comment: Please take a look at a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550844/identify-if-java-cannot-be-executed-in-widows-batch-script

Comment: @Patrick Cuff what if the java executable within the code (line 4) is derived from a variable: `for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%JAVA_HOME% -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"')` - in such cases, how can I specify quotes? Just using quotes around JAVA_HOME does not seem to work!

Comment: @Neel try adding %JAVA_HOME% (just the bin directory) to the front of the PATH (you have setlocal specified so it is only valid for the scope of the bat file).
`SET PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%'`
`for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"')` etc

Comment: Small clarification to the last comment based on https://superuser.com/a/940139/459204: to add JAVA_HOME to PATH, use `set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"`

Answer (score 4):

I've made some modification to [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675459/how-to-get-java-version-from-batch-script/5675868#5675868) so it works with Java 9, 10, etc.
This returns minor version for 1.x, and major version for Java 9, 10, etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem We use the value the JAVACMD environment variable, if defined
rem and then try JAVA_HOME
set "_JAVACMD=%JAVACMD%"
if "%_JAVACMD"=="" (
  if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" (
    if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
  )
)
if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" set _JAVACMD=java

rem Parses x out of 1.x; for example 8 out of java version 1.8.0_xx
rem Otherwise, parses the major version; 9 out of java version 9-ea
set JAVA_VERSION=0
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%_JAVACMD% -Xms32M -Xmx32M -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
  set JAVA_VERSION=%%g
)
set JAVA_VERSION=%JAVA_VERSION:"=%
for /f "delims=.-_ tokens=1-2" %%v in ("%JAVA_VERSION%") do (
  if /I "%%v" EQU "1" (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%w
  ) else (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%v
  )
)

@echo %JAVA_VERSION%

endlocal
```

echoes `8` or `17` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This will extract the minor part of the version number:

```
java -version 2>&1 | awk '/version/ {print $3}' | awk -F . '{print $2}'
```

However, it may be better to extract the major.minor and match on that in case Oracle ever change the version number scheme again e.g.:

```
java -version 2>&1 | awk '/version/ {print $3}' | egrep -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Owen. awk does not work on windows, I used the same in linux, but yours seem better here is mine java -version 2>&1 | head -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | cut -d'.' -f2

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry, I didn't read closely enough to notice it was Windows.

Comment: It's ok and it seems I need 15 reputation to vote up. I am new to this site, will do it when I have enough reputation on this site. Thanks again!

Comment: Save it for Patrick who answered the question you actually asked :)

Comment: On Windows you can also use PowerShell to do something similar: `$a = [regex]::matches((java -version 2>&1),"[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]_[0-9]{2}")[1].value; $a.split(".")`. You can access the version components by their index; [0] = major, [1] = minor, [2] = build.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_+^" %j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do @set "jver=%j%k%l%m"
```

This will store the java version into **`jver`** variable and as integer
And you can use it for comparisons .E.G

```
if %jver% LSS 16000 echo not supported version
```

.You can use more major version by removing %k and %l and %m.This command prompt version.

***For .bat use this:***

```
@echo off
PATH %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_+^" %%j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
```

According to my tests this is the fastest way to get the java version from bat (as it uses only internal commands and not external ones as `FIND`,`FINDSTR` and does not use `GOTO` which also can slow the script). Some JDK vendors does not support `-fullversion` switch or their implementation is not the same as this one provided by Oracle (better avoid them).

Comment: I get this? `jver=1705+8LTS`

Comment: @rogerdpack - what is the output of `java -fullversion` ?

Comment: `openjdk full version "17.0.5+8-LTS"`

Comment: @rogerdpack - I've updated the answer. Can you retry it?