# identify if java cannot be executed in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote the below batch script which asks for a `JAVA_HOME` path if its not present in environment, and then it verifies the java version. but before identifying java version it should also check whether `java` is present in the path (can be executed) or not. Please help me figure out if `java -version` can be executed or not and display proper message

```
@echo off
setlocal

set VERSION5="1.5"

IF "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
echo Enter path to JAVA_HOME: 
set /p JAVA_HOME=
goto check_java_version
) ELSE (
echo Using %JAVA_HOME%
goto check_java_version
)


:check_java_version
 for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (

set JAVAVER=%%g
)

set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:"=%

set JAVAVER=%JAVAVER:java version =%

for /f "delims=. tokens=1-3" %%v in ("%JAVAVER%") do (
set VER=%%w
)

if not "%VER%" GEQ "5" goto wrong_version
set JAVA_BIN=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin
goto correct_java_version


:correct_java_version
REM echo JAVA Version is ok.
set JAVA_LIB=%cd%/lib

%JAVA_BIN%/java -cp %JAVA_LIB%/csm-runtime-1.0.jar;%JAVA_LIB%/groovy-all-1.8.1.jar;%JAVA_LIB%/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar;%JAVA_LIB%/csm-dbutil-1.0.jar;%JAVA_LIB%/commons-exec-1.1.jar;%JAVA_LIB%/log4j-1.2.8.jar;%JAVA_LIB%/commons-cli-1.2.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=com/ABC/csm/log4j.xml -Dendorsed_plugins_dir=./plugins    com.ABC.csm.CSMMain %* 
goto end_java_version

:wrong_version
echo Current JDK Version %VER%
echo Expected JDK %VERSION5% or greater. Please fix your SSATOP and try again.
goto end_java_version

:no_java
echo No JDK found in %JAVA_HOME%.
goto wrong_version

:end_java_version
endlocal
```

1 of the examples of invalid condition would be, instead of providing `JAVA_HOME` i.e., e:\csm\java I gave it as e:\csm\java\jre\bin which in this case should display proper error message that `please provide a JAVA_HOME` path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the existence of a program in the `PATH`, windows batch provides the `~%PATH:` option of the `SET` command. See `HELP CALL` or `HELP FOR`.

Use this piece of code as a starting point.

```
:ProgInPath
set PROG=%~$PATH:1
goto :eof
```

and use it like this

```
call :ProgInPath java.exe
IF "%PROG%" == "" (
  echo Java.exe not found
) else (
  echo. %PROG%
)
```

in this example, if `java.exe` is in the `PATH`, it echoes its complete filespec.

Answer (score 0):

I used  the below snippet and it solved my problem

```
:check_java_existence
IF EXIST %JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe (
echo java exists
) ELSE (
echo java does not exists
)
```