# How to get java version using single command in Windows command prompt?

Tags: java, regex, windows, command

I need to fetch java version `1.6.0_26` from the below `java -version` output

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Please help me getting `1.6.0_26`

Note: I don't need power shell or any external programs

**UPDATE**

I came up with `java -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version"` which give me below output

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
```

now even a java way of **pattern matching** or **regex** will work for me :)

Comment: Describe your end goal? Perhaps there is a better way. And isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675459/how-to-get-java-version-from-batch-script

Comment: @Pangea: the link gets javaversion using a batch file, I needed something through which I get javaversion `1.6.0_26` directly using a one liner, since I cannot deploy my batch file in customers machine

Comment: Why not just call for the [java.version](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.specification.version%2Cjava.version%2Cjava.vm.specification.version&format=TSV) property in code and either use that directly or write it to a new blank line in the file?  Otherwise I really can't see what Java (as a programming language) has to do with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the solution from the question Pangea linked to in a single line:

```
    
c:\>for /f "tokens=3" %g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do @echo %g
"1.6.0_24"
c:\>for /f "tokens=3" %g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do ( @set v=%g & @echo %v:~1,8% )
1.6.0_24
```

I just checked and it seems my second example only works with Windows7, the following works for me on Windows XP (so it should work on Windows7 as well)

```
for /f "tokens=3" %g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do ( @echo %~g )
```

Comment: I know its too much to ask but still `"` cannot be removed?

Comment: See my edit. However this assumes a certain length of the response which might not always work well.

Comment: Hmm, works for me. Do you have the "Command Extensions" enabled? They are by default and that's what enables the `%v:~1,8%` syntax

Comment: I have no idea what you just said :P what do you mean by "Command Extensions" Also I need to go with whatever comes by default

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: see my edit. It seems the first syntax only works under Windows7

Answer (score 3):

you can do it from single line from command promt
**C:>java -version**

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
java -version 2>&1 | awk '/version/ {print $3}' | egrep -o '[^\"]*'
```

Comment: Bollocs, haven't noticed that earlier

Comment: you might want to delete your answer, as people may down vote

Comment: Actually, this answer is perfectly valid with a [Windows port of the UNIX utils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/).

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do @set "jver=%j%k%l%m"
```

This will store the java version into **`jver`** variable and as integer
And you can use it for comparisons .E.G

```
if %jver% LSS 16000 echo not supported version
```

.You can use more major version by removing %k and %l and %m.This command prompt version.

***For .bat use this:***

```
@echo off
PATH %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\
for /f tokens^=2-5^ delims^=.-_^" %%j in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do set "jver=%%j%%k%%l%%m"
```

According to my tests this is the fastest way to get the java version from bat (as it uses only internal commands and not external ones as `FIND`,`FINDSTR` and does not use `GOTO` which also can slow the script). Some JDK vendors does not support `-fullversion` switch or their implementation is not the same as this one provided by Oracle (better avoid them).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below function to fetch java version `1.6.0_26`

```
String regexMatch(String myInput, String myRegex)
{
String ResultString
Pattern regex
Matcher regexMatcher

regex = Pattern.compile(myRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);

regexMatcher = regex.matcher(myInput);

List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}

for(int i=0;i<matchList.size();i++)
{
    myInput=myInput.replaceAll( matchList[i], '')
}
return myInput;
}
```

and call

```
rs=regexMatch(rs,"[a-zA-Z\"]+")
```

where `rs="java version \"1.6.0_26\""`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @a_horse_with_no_name but detecting first if command exists.

```
where java > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
    set java_v="Command not found"
) else (
    for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do set java_v=%%g
)
echo  Java: %java_v:~1,8%
```