# How to remove empty row and "()" output from Java version check script

Tags: windows, command-prompt, geneos

I have a windows command line script to run to check the [java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675459/how-to-get-java-version-from-batch-script), but it is outputting two additional rows(2 & 3) I don't need.  I need it only to display the Echo of Current Java Version and the Java version number(1 & 3).  Can you possibly assist with how I can modify the script?

1. Current Java Version
2. empty row
3. C:\Program Files \Java|jre7\bin>()
4. "1.7.0_161"

**Command being used:**

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c echo Current Java Version & C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c  "for /f "tokens=3" %g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (@echo %g)"
```

**Output from cmd window:**

[image: cmd_window]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Java Version from batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675459/how-to-get-java-version-from-batch-script)

Comment: Not quite.  I am trying to modify that script to get just one output, but it is bringing back an empty row and ().  The other script did not have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the ( ) around the echo call after "do" as shown below.  That resolved my issue:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c echo Current Java Version & C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c  "for /f "tokens=3" %g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do **@echo %g**"
```